# How to solve Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState in android

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

Hi I am developing small android application in which I am using Sherlock actionbar. My application contains following things. one main activity which contains 2 fragments and one sample activity. So what i want to do on button click inside fragment one start new sample activity. I am starting sample activity for result. on activity result what I want to do swap tab to Tab2 that is another tab. I did this in following way

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "click on button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SampleActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
}
```

and on activity result what I want to do

```
 @Override @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 7)
    {
            getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
    }
}
```

So when I tried to do `getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1);`
it shows me following error :

```
08-08 16:05:21.596: E/AndroidRuntime(6885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 16:05:21.596: E/AndroidRuntime(6885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure        delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65543, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.sampletabapp/com.example.sampletabapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

Any one having solution for this.Need help thank you.

Here is sample project regarding this issue https://www.dropbox.com/s/0d61i9ccol189tv/SampleTabAppZIP.tar.gz. you can check what is actual problem. Any one having solution for this please help. thank you.

Comment: Any one have solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflicts with immediate execution on the UI thread during lifecycle methods, you can  use the [various post() methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) or implement your own [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

I prefer the Handler pattern.

I recommend your Handler be declared as a private static inner class, and have it hold a `WeakRefence` to whatever it will be manipulating, most likely the fragment.  The weak reference will help avoid memory leaks if the fragment is repeatedly run through it's life cycle methods.

```
private static MyHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MyFragment> ref;

    public MyHandler(MyFragment fragment) {
        ref = new WeakReference<MyFragment>(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        MyFragment fragment = ref.get();
        if (fragment != null) {
            //do whatever you want to do.
            //For example:
            fragment.someCallbackMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your fragment, all you have to do is send a message to your handler inside the `onClick()` method

```
@Override
public void OnClick(View v) {
    handler.sendMessage(new Message());
}
```